# Angular - Como hacer http.Post con query parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, strava

Estoy trabajando con la API de Strava y tengo la siguiente duda. Si pruebo desde Postman con mi client_secret y con el code correspondiente me funciona

[image: Como hago la petición en postman]

Pero esto mismo, llevado a Angular, me estoy volviendo loco para hacerlo funcionar, ahora mismo tengo esto, y me da todo el rato bad Request, sin mas información.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano para lanzar la petición, por que, creo, que estoy metiendo mal esos params (los que veis en Postman)

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    const body = JSON.stringify({})
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('client_id', environment.client_id)
      .set('client_secret', environment.client_secret)
      .set('code', code)
      .set('grant_type', environment.grant_type)

    this.http
         .post<any>('https://www.strava.com/oauth/token', body, {
           headers: headers,
           params: params
         })
        .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors))
        .subscribe((res) => console.log(res))
```

**EDITADO**

He añadido los .append, como comentáis y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    const body = JSON.stringify({})
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .append('client_id', environment.client_id)
      .append('client_secret', environment.client_secret)
      .append('code', code)
      .append('grant_type', environment.grant_type)
      
    this.http
         .post<any>('https://www.strava.com/oauth/token', body, {
           headers: headers,
           params: params
         })
        // .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors))
        .subscribe((res) => console.log(res))
```

Y el error que da es el siguiente:

[image: consola chrome con errores]

**EDIT 2**

He seguido trabajando, he creado un injector para controlar los errores, pero me estoy volviendo loco, no entiendo porque funciona desde Postman y no desde Angular

[image: Consola de depuración con errores]

Os adjunto la captura de los errores y de como están formateados los headers y el body antes de lanzar la petición. Me mosquea que no sean de tipo Key - Value y que sean Key - Array. No se si esto es normal

Por otro lado os adjunto el nuevo código a ver si veis algo raro

```
refreshToken(code: string){
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })

    const body = new HttpParams({
      fromObject : {
        client_id: environment.client_id,
        client_secret: environment.client_secret,
        code: code,
        grant_type: environment.grant_type
      }
    })

    this.http
        .post<any>('https://www.strava.com/oauth/token', body, {
          headers: headers
          //params: params
        })
        .subscribe((res) => console.log(res))
  }
```

Por si sirviese para aclarar algo, dejo aquí el [link directo a la documentación](https://developers.strava.com/docs/getting-started/#oauth), pero yo veo todo correcto

Comment: Podrias mostrar el error que estas obteniendo?

Comment: no deberias hacer un append()  en lugar de un set?

Comment: @Bryro es exactamente lo que debe hacer

Comment: Prueba con esta respuesta y dinos si lo solucionaste https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470575/angular-4-httpclient-query-parameters

Comment: Hola os he añadido lo que comentabais, voy a seguir la respuesta que adjuntas Andres

Comment: He revisado las soluciones que proponen en ese post y son todas para métodos get @AndresGardiol

Comment: Hola a todos, he añadido el EDIT2 al post original a ver si me podéis echar una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final el problema de todo era el fichero routes, no estaban bien configuradas las rutas, por lo tanto, como sale de la aplicación y vuelve a entrar, para la autenticación OAUTH2 de Strava, aquí se volvía loco.

Para solucionar esto, he dejado el routes de la siguiente manera

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'oauth', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'oauth', component: OauthComponent },
  { path: 'authorization', component: AuthorizationComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'oauth'}
];
```

Realmente, me faltaban los nodos `path: ''` y `path: '**'`

Respecto al código que hemos ido viendo estos días, ha quedado de la siguiente manera.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().append(
            'Content-Type',
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        );

        const body = {};

        const params = new HttpParams()
            .append('client_id', environment.client_id)
            .append('client_secret', environment.client_secret)
            .append('code', code)
            .append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');

        this.http
            .post<any>('https://www.strava.com/oauth/token', body, {
                headers: headers,
                params: params,
            })
            .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```